# Nested trig asymptotics

Tags: trigonometry, asymptotics

Letting $\ \ \sin^n(x)=\underbrace{\sin\circ \sin\circ\dots\circ \sin(x)}_{n\text{ times}}\ $,

is it true that $\ \ \sin^n(\pi/2)\sim \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{n}}?$

More specifically, is it true that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2\sqrt{3 n}-\sum_{x=1}^{n}\sin^x(\pi/2)=2\pi+C$$

where $C\approx \dfrac{1}{2}$?

Comment: In the definition of $\sin^n$ it would appear that $n$ is a natural number; how can you use it as an integration variable?

Comment: @Justpassingby not sure on standard teerminology - area under discrete curve ...

Comment: so it's really a $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^k (\pi/2)$, not $\int_{x=1}^n \sin^x(\pi/2)$?

Comment: @gt6989b yes, corrected

Comment: Did you take the problem from here http://jonathan.bergknoff.com/journal/iterated-sine ?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo no - just from messing around. - Good find - thanks! :)

Comment: I note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\sin^n(x))$$  This way, we can see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^n(x)=0$, regardless of $x$, which seems to fit your first question.