# Maximum of $\sin(x)$ with increased iterations

Tags: trigonometry, locus

My question is about composing sines. When you compose $\sin x$ ($x$ in radians of course) $k$ times, what is the maximum in terms of $k$?

For example, composing $2$ sines, as in $\sin(\sin x)$, attains a maximum of approximately $0.84147$ because $\sin(\sin\pi/2) = \sin1 \approx 0.84147$ and the value at $ x = \pi/2$ will obviously always be the maximum for any number of iterations.

So, the question is, does there exist an elementary function $f$ that takes the number of iterations and outputs the maximum of that many nested sines? That is, can $f$ given by $$
f(k)=\underbrace{\left(\sin\circ\cdots\circ\sin\right)}_{k \text{ compositions}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
be expressed using elementary functions, excluding trigonometric functions?

I have fiddled around some but I cannot get the correct function to match a locus I made.

Comment: Check out this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1ztqht/i_have_some_questions_exploring_infinitelynested/). It is unlikely that this can be described by an elementary function, but if you have a specific range for the number of iterations in mind, you can fit an exponential/rational function curve to the points.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Iterating $\sin(x)$, $n$ times can be closely approximated by $\sqrt{3/n}$ for large $n$..

Comment: There are many related in-site posts, yet somehow the system fails to put them on the right of the "Related" block. Just to establish at least some connections, here's a [failed(?) post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58677) and one [minimally related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685485) regarding the basics. And then there's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193788) that is dup-linked to a "node".

Comment: Falling on this way a long time after the question . See below.

Answer (score 1):

Using Frequency Modulation and Bessel functions you can write $\sin^n$ as a matrix product ( see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297398/fourier-series-of-iterated-sin-diagonalization-of-an-infinite-matrix-of-bessel) ). It involves just sine functions with relatively elementary coefficients based on Besssel function you can find even in Excel !

And the maximum comes as powers of the eigenvalues of the Bessel matrix:
$$ \sin^n(\pi/2) \approx \pi/2  - 0.2385 \ln( 10 n +1 )  \qquad \text{ for 0<n<1} $$
$$ \sin^n(\pi/2) \approx 1- 0.222 \ln( n )   \qquad \text{ for 1<n } $$